# display updated price when product options changes magento issue

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

i printed the product price in magento product page with 
`<?php  echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($_product->getPrice());  ?>`

I have also installed a colow swatch with allows user to change the color of product, what i need to fo is get the updated price when user changes the color from the color swatch..

any hints on where to look..

Answer (score 1):

While creating simple associated product for particular color through Quick Create, there is a price option also.
You can change the price there which will be updated as you select the attribute.